# How can I check if a file starting with a letter is in the folder?

Tags: batch, batch-file, ms-dos

Why does this script always return "A" even when there are no files starting with A in the folder, but there being files starting with B and C?

```
@ECHO OFF

if exist %cd%\a* goto A
if exist %cd%\b* goto B
if exist %cd%\c* goto C

:a 
echo A
pause
exit

:b
echo B
pause
exit

:c
echo C
pause
exit
```

Comment: You need an `exit` after the condition checks: if none is true, the code will continue to execute at `:a`.

Comment: This would achieve the same: `for %%# in (a b c) do if exist "%cd%\%%#*" (Echo %%#&Pause&exit)`

Comment: @LotPings How would you exclude folders with that? As it still triggers for A when there is a folder starting with A in the same directory.

Comment: Isn't this question more suited to StackOverflow?

Comment: That's a new different question. See syntax of `if /?` and insert an `if not ...`

Answer (score 0):

Add three lines after your last test:

> echo Nothing Found
>
> pause
>
> exit

Comment: That would still return just A though, never B or C. Or does the tests also include folders?

Comment: I did. I added after the line `if exist %cd%\c* goto C` and still got "A".

Comment: Odd, it worked correctly when I tried it.

Comment: also when there is a folder starting with "A" in the folder you start the batch file from?